# Floating window appears with all pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a simple website using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

I have a floating window written in JavaScript but this floating window appears only on the home page as I linked it there.

My question is: how can I make the floating window appear with all pages? (I mean the same floating window)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the same window on every page without reloading the page? Or is reloading no problem?

If reloading is no problem then you can use the solution from zIndex.

Otherwise you will have to change the whole base of your site to make it load with AJAX since you cannot keep an iFrame when you go from page to page without reloading the iFrame every page visit.

Answer (score 0):

Have a common .js file and in that write a function to create your "Floating window" with DOM(appendChild,createElement..etc) and call this function from every page however you like and voila.Be sure to use removeChild when you close one page so that a new element with the same id is created everytime and there is no discrepancies